# Anchor Footer UITableView

Tags: ios6, uitableview, footer

I implemented `-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section` and my footer shows up below the last UITableView cell. So far so good.

Is there a way to make the footer view stick to the bottom of the screen? If there are only a few rows to the table view it is kind of weird that there is white after the footer. In CSS I would be looking for something like `bottom: 0px`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the view you use as a footer at the bottom of the screen, you anyway get white space between the last table view cell and the footer if there are not enough cells.

If you want a fixed view at the bottom of the screen you will need to separate it from the table view. You would have a standard view controller with two subviews, your footer and the table view.

That means you have to change the `UITableViewController` to a `UIViewController`. This involves adding your table view manually as a property, declaring and assigning `datasource` and `delegate` in the interface declaration.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I slowly have been figuring that that would be the only solution.